# How to post a json object to controller using dojo ajax?

Tags: dojo

I am trying to search details when i give a category or task in drop down.
The name of the particular form using `dijit/form/Form`  that does the searching is searchForm.

I have converted the entries into json and trying to post these details using dojo ajax. When I try this,I am not getting the dropdown and I am getting a text box instead.

```js
dojo.xhrPost({
    url: "/filter.q4",
    postData: dojo.formToJson("searchForm");
    headers : {
        "Content-Type" : "application/json,charset=utf-8"
    },
    load: function(response,ioargs) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error : function(response,ioargs) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your obvious error is here:

```js
postData: dojo.formToJson("searchForm");
```

Note the trailing semicolon?  That's your problem.  You want a comma, instead:

```js
postData: dojo.formToJson("searchForm"),
```

This should get you past your immediate issue.